# Invalid Syntax erroe python

Tags: python

I'm currently trying to complete my coursework and for some reason I keep on getting a invalid syntax. The part that doesn't work is the first class no, it originally worked but now has stopped so I don't know if it's my software or something.. My code is below:

```
import random
score = 0
questions = 0
classnumber = ("1","2","3")
name= input("Enter Your Username: ")
print("Hello, " + name+(". Welcome to the Arithmetic Quiz")

classno = input("What class are you in?"))
    while group not in classnumber:
        print("Enter a valid class")
        classno=input("What class are you in?")

while questions <10:
    for i in range(10):
        number1=random.randint(1,10)
        number2=random.randint(1,10)
        op=random.choice("*-+")
        multiply=num1*num2
        subtract=num1-num2
        addition=num1+num2

        if op == "-": 
            print("Please enter your answer.")
            questions+=1
            print(" Question" ,questions, "/10")
            uinput=input(str(number1)+" - "+str(number2))
            if uinput == str(subtract):
                score+=1
                print("Correct, your score is: " ,score,)
            else:
                print ("Incorrect, the answer is: " +str(subtract))
                score+=0

        if op == "+":
            print("Please enter your answer.")
            questions+=1
            print(" Question",questions, "/10")
            uinput=input(str(number1)+" + "+str(number2))
            if uinput == str(addition):
                score+=1
                print("  Correct, your score is: ",score,)
            else:
                print("  Incorrect, the answer is: " +str(addition))
                score+=0

        if op == "*":
            print("Please enter you answer.")
            questions+=1
            print(" Question",questions, "/10")
            uinput=input(str(number1)+" * "+str(number2))
            if uinput == str(multiply):
                score+=1
                print("  Correct, your score is: " ,score,)
            else:
                print("  Incorrect, the answer is: " +str(multiply))
                score+=0

if score >9:
    print("Well done," ,name1, "your score is" ,score, "/10")
else:
 print(name1," your score is " ,score, "/10")

def no1():
     with open("class1.txt", 'a')as file:
         file.write(str(name1)+str( score)+"\n")
def no2():
     with open("class2.txt", 'a')as file:
         file.write(str(name1)+str( score)+"\n")
def no3():
     with open("class3.txt", 'a')as file:
         file.write(str(name1)+str( score)+"\n")
if group=="1":
    no1()
if group=="2":
    no2()
if group=="3":
    no3()
```

Comment: Please include the actual output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have extra brackets on these lines

```
print("Hello, " + name+(". Welcome to the Arithmetic Quiz") # line 6 | open bracket

classno = input("What class are you in?")) # line 8 | close bracket
```

You have also not defined `group` anywhere. I think you mean to say

```
while classno not in classnumber:
```

Comment: Thanks, sort of new to python.

Comment: All good. Sometimes the errors explain a lot, sometimes not. Few more things I'm going to point out and will add to answer in a sec

Comment: If you found this response to answer your question appropriately then you can accept the answer for your question.

Comment: Don't know if I should make a new topic for this, but can I do the quiz three times by adding a loop before the loop that is happening?

Comment: Yep, you can have a while loop in a for loop. If you only want 3 times then `for x in range(0, 3) # x will be 0, 1, 2 since range excludes last value` will work